# Gracefully Handle Losing Connection Exported X Display

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, x11

I am exporting a several GUIs across a network using X11, I start the GUIs by SSHing into the server with the -X option and running the executable.

If the remote machine is abruptly shutdown or the connection is lost the Window on the local machine stops responding and cannot be closed by normal means (such as clicking the close icon in the top right). This happens with a Java Swing GUI and a QT GUI.

Is there a X11 or SSH config parameter I can set which will cause the window to close nicely if the connection is lost?

Being able to set a timeout would be ideal.

Comment: A VNC would be another option, as when the connection drops, you would simply reconnect to the existing session that would still be running whatever applications.

Comment: Its unlikely that using a different method of screen sharing is possible, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the fairly low-level **xkill** utility, which if given with no args allows you to click on a window of the X11 client you wish to close the connection to. Perhaps your window manager also provides a "kill" item in its 
menus.

---

You can configure ssh to detect a lost connection more quickly by editing `~/.ssh/config`, on the machine on which you give the ssh command, to end with the lines:

```
# --- all following applies to myserver only
Host myserver
ServerAliveCountMax 3
ServerAliveInterval 5
```

Use the `Host` command to restrict the options that follow it to only host `myserver`. The client will send a message to the server every 5 seconds, and when 3 go without
reply it will close the connection.

Comment: I was hoping for more of an automated process, this is so that the end user does not get stuck with a non responsive window.

Comment: I added to my answer how to config ssh for quicker timeouts.

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks promising! I'll let you know how it goes.